# EBCDIC (Cp1047) junit 0D25

Tags: java, ebcdic

I'm working with some data encoded in EBCDIC and I'm required to substitute some of the values.

One of the values is the hex bytes `0D 25` which have to become `40 40`.

I understand this to mean that the EBCDIC characters are as follows:

- 0D: carriage return
- 25: line feed

This pair when found in a `String` with this encoding must be replaced with two spaces (hex 40, twice). See also the [wikipedia EDCDIC character table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC).

I understand `0D` (carriage return) to be equivalent to `\r` and `25`  (line feed) is (should be?) `\n` in UTF-16. Therefore:

```
assertThat(minimalExample("\r\n")).isEqualTo(" ");
```

should pass, given a minimal method defined as follows

```
String minimalExample(String raw) throws Exception {
    byte[] bytes = raw.getBytes("Cp1047");
    if (bytes[0] == 0x0d && bytes[1] == 0x25) {
        bytes[0] = 0x40;
        bytes[1] = 0x40;
    }
    return new String(bytes, "Cp1047");
}
```

What I end up getting though is

```
Expecting:
 <"
">
to be equal to:
 <" ">
but was not.
```

Because the second hex value for the given string is `15` (not `25` like I thought it would be).

It seems that `25` is represented in UTF-16 as `\u0085`.

Is this correct?

Comment: Note that the jt400 project has a lot of conversion tables from the as/400 that might be simpler to use.

Comment: You should not convert bytes to and from hex strings just to check their values.  You can just write `if (bytes[0] == 0x0d && bytes[1] == 0x25)`.

Comment: @VGR thanks for pointing that out, I guess I'd been looking at the problem too much. I updated the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The EBCDIC newline character got a separate Unicode *code point* NEL = U+0085. For instance BufferedReader.readLine will also take that as line separator.

EBCDIC LF 0X25 is not `\n` but `\u0085`.
`\n` is always `\u000a`. UTF-16.

The unit test should be done on `byte[]` and it should be checked that the code reading lines does not read an extra empty line on bytes 0d 25 in EBCDIC.

In regular expression you can use `"\\R"` for the miscellaneous line separators:

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\R", ".");
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped point me in the right direction. I'm not reading lines, just replacing characters.

Comment: In EBCDIC, at least on IBM's z/OS operating system, the newline character `NL` is 0x15! For example, ASCII sequence 0x0D 0x0A will be transformed to 0x15 when uploading to z/OS, and vice versa when downloadindg from z/OS (with default settings on the z/OS FTP server).

Comment: @phunsoft there are some variants of EBCDIC. One almost wonders whether there was some historic Eb working at IBM.

Comment: @Joop Eggen I know all to well about the Problems all those variants cause. But the NL is invariant across all those code pages, isn't it?

Comment: @phunsoft yes NL is 0x15. Unicode numbering all symbols picked U+0085 with name NEL for the EBCDIC newline. And Java uses Unicode for text. But I have no idea how LF, 0x25, and all used. It is 20 years ago, AS/400 etc. So I really appreciate better info. Consider providing an answer.

Comment: @phunsoft to be clear in this case: a Java application should load an EBCDIC text file with char `'\u0085' ` as newline. We are then already talking about Unicode. Java handles CR+LF (Windows), LF (Unix) and NL (z/OS) well, for instance stripping them when reading text lines. It is maybe strange no conversion is done, as in C for CR+LF and LF, and an extra NEL was added.